# Github issue form: add label based on dropdown

Tags: github

I'm currently looking at the new YAML based issue templates at Github and would like to achieve a system where a label is assigned to the issue dependent on the value the issue creator selects from a dropdown.

I couldn't find anything on this.
For example I have the following bug template:

```
name: Bug Report
description: File a bug report
labels: [triage]
body:
  - type: dropdown
    id: bug-type
    attributes:
      label: Project
      multiple: true
      options:
        - API
        - WebUI
    validations:
      required: true
```

How could I add a label "api" and/or "webui" based on the selection of the dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple Actions for this now, for example:

[RegEx Issue Labeler](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/regex-issue-labeler)

Regex-based, matches against the issue body.

[Advanced Issue Labeler](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/advanced-issue-labeler)

Uses [github-issue-parser](https://github.com/stefanbuck/github-issue-parser) to parse the body into a JSON string. Requires checking-out the code in order to access data from the issue form(s).